# Remove a specific division, if one of its child elements' attribute satisfies a certain criteria

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I want to remove a specific division (e.g., `Feed_body_3R0rO`), if its (indirect) parent division has certain id (e.g., `app`), and one of its (indirect) child division's attribute is `title` and its value satisfies a certain criteria (e.g., `nickname === "key"`):

The first variable (`feeds`) works fine, but the second (`nicknames`) always returns an empty list.

May I have some help about why is it like that?

```js
var feeds = document.querySelector("div#app")

//console.log("div app:")
//console.log(feeds)

var nicknames = feeds.querySelectorAll(".Feed_body_3R0rO a span[title]")

console.log("nicknames:")
console.log(nicknames)
```

```html
<div id="app">
... (many layers of divisions...)

<div class="Feed_body_3R0rO">
... (many layers of divisions...)
  <div class="woo-box-item-flex head_main_3DRDm">
     <div class="woo-box-flex woo-box-column woo-box-justifyCenter head_content_wrap_27749">
        <div class="woo-box-flex woo-box-alignCenter head_nick_1yix2">
           <a class="ALink_default_2ibt1 head_cut_2Zcft head_name_24eEB" href="/u/123456789"><span title="myNickName">myNickName</span></a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
... (many layers of divisions...)
</div>

... (many layers of divisions...)
</div>
```

Comment: Your code should return a list. By the way, how your code satisfies the condition.......its value satisfies a certain criteria (e.g., nickname === "key")

Comment: @Mamun I haven't added this part yet, because current I cannot locate the exact division I'm trying to work on.

Comment: I have updated the question executable code snippet. Please execute and see how it is returning a list.

Comment: @Mamun Thank you very much! I guess the problem is on other sections of my project then :(

Answer (score 0):

I tested with your example and the querySelectors are working.

All I can think of is that maybe you trying to select elements that are not present yet.
Are you by any chance you filling the nicknames HTML part asynchronously?

Comment: I didn't edit the webpage after it is loaded and the script is in content.js, which should has its default `run_at` value, i.e. `document_idle`

Comment: If you can share more of the code base maybe I can help. On the other hand is the javascript being loaded at the top or the bottom of the HTML?